# MySQL GROUP BY column ignorning specific value

Tags: mysql

I have a query on a table of phone calls that uses GROUP BY to show only unique caller ids. The problem is that if a caller has caller id blocking their caller id shows up as "Unknown" and the client doesn't want all Unknowns to be summed up together. So basically, instead of just `GROUP BY caller_id` I need to somehow do something like `GROUP BY caller_id IF caller_id != 'Unknown'`

Is this even possible? I'd like to avoid doing all the group processing in PHP if at all possible.

Comment: Isn't the WHERE statement for this?

Comment: The answer by VladoDemcak seems ok... does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

`SELECT caller_id  FROM phone_calls WHERE caller_id != 'Unknown' GROUP BY caller_id;`

or consider **DISTINCT** - in most cases it is faster - if you have **index** created on caller_id the performance is usually the same, but if not DISTINCT is better. If you need :

> ... show only unique caller ids ..

but maybe for your case (doing aggregation or something similar) you are not able to use it but just in case:

`SELECT DISTINCT caller_id FROM phone_calls WHERE  caller_id != 'Unknown'`;

**-- EDIT AFTER discussion in comments**

```
SELECT * FROM callers;                                                                                                                                                                                             
+----+-----------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| id | caller_id | call_time |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  1 | abc       |        24 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  2 | abc       |        16 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  3 | xyz       |        10 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  4 | xyz       |        10 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  5 | Unknown   |        11 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  6 | Unknown   |        12 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  7 | Unknown   |        13 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  8 | xyz       |         1 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
|  9 | abc       |        10 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-----------+-----------+   

SELECT caller_id, SUM(call_time) FROM callers 
WHERE caller_id != 'Unknown' 
GROUP BY caller_id;                                                                                                                     
+-----------+----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| caller_id | SUM(call_time) |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| abc       |             50 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| xyz       |             21 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        

SELECT caller_id, SUM(call_time) FROM callers
GROUP BY caller_id;                                                                                                                                                  
+-----------+----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| caller_id | SUM(call_time) |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| abc       |             50 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| Unknown   |             36 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
| xyz       |             21 |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+-----------+----------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                        

SELECT caller_id, SUM(call_time) as total_time FROM callers 
WHERE caller_id != 'Unknown' 
GROUP BY caller_id 
UNION 
SELECT caller_id, call_time FROM callers 
WHERE caller_id = 'Unknown';                             
+-----------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| caller_id | total_time |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+-----------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| abc       |         50 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| xyz       |         21 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| Unknown   |         11 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| Unknown   |         12 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| Unknown   |         13 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+-----------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                             

SELECT caller_id, SUM(call_time) as total_time FROM callers
GROUP BY caller_id, 
      (case when caller_id = 'Unknown' 
       AND id is not null 
       then id end
       );                                                                   
+-----------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| caller_id | total_time |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+-----------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| abc       |         50 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| Unknown   |         11 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| Unknown   |         12 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| Unknown   |         13 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| xyz       |         21 |                                                                                                                                                                                                             
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: We are doing aggregation, so DISTINCT doesn't work. And we still want the Unknown calls to appear, just each as their own group (so each call with a caller id of Unknown will appear in the results with a COUNT of 1) and I think the WHERE clause will strip them out completely. It would work if I just made a second query to only select the calls with a caller_id of Unknown and not do any grouping on that second query though

Comment: Ok now i understand what you really need. There is one possibility but now i cannot test it but you can try "group by caller_id, (case when caller_id = 'Unknown' and unique_col is not null then unique_col end);" but there must be unique column for Unknown group. Otherwise I think you will need two selects and union them.

Comment: @awestover89 check my answer I added examples It would be interesting for you

Comment: I ended up making a variable. The query in question was already about 60 lines long so a UNION would have been horribly inefficient. My final solution ended up being something along the lines of: IF (0 = ani REGEXP '^[+]?[0-9]+$',@ani_count:=@ani_count+1,@ani_count:=0) AS unknown_count and then added unknown_count to the group. I think functionally this behaves the same way as your last example.

Comment: Basically I created a variable that would be the same for all numeric caller ids, and a unique value for any non-numeric caller_id, so when I group on ani and unknown_count, non-numeric caller ids are each in a solo group.